# "По мнению" обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

По мнению спикера сената Казахстана Дариги Назарбаевой(,) аграрный спектр в Казахстане находится в упадке.

Обособляется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122) (Розенталь, § 25)

1. Вводные слова и словосочетания выделяются запятыми. Различается несколько основных групп вводных слов по их значению:

...

5) вводные слова (сочетания), указывающие на источник сообщения (*говорят, сообщают, передают, по словам..., по сообщению..., по сведениям..., **по мнению...**, по-моему, по-твоему, по-нашему, по-вашему, на мой взгляд, с точки зрения, по слухам, по преданию, помнится, слышно, дескать, как говорят, как пишут, как известно* и др.): ***По словам капитана***, до ближайшего порта остаётся два дня пути (Гонч.); *Я, **помню**, весной возвращался от вас* (А. Т.); *Но, **по слухам**, какая-то часть упорно сражалась под Каменском* (Ф.); *Фабричные здания, **на мой взгляд**, ничем не отличались от тех, что я видел по другим заводам округа* (Баж.).

Answer (score 0):

Да, выражения *"по чьему-то мнению"* или *"по мнению кого-то"* обособляются. Цитирую [Грамоту](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_189):

> Иногда вводные слова указывают *на источник информации,* которую сообщает говорящий. Вводные словосочетания в этом случае начинаются словами ПО СООБЩЕНИЮ, ПО СЛОВАМ, ПО МНЕНИЮ. Например: *Вам, **по мнению** врачей, нужно на время прервать тренировки.*